# Can you trigger a script on formsubmit plus 2 minutes?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that I want to run when a new form entry has been submitted 
but I want to run a query on the form entry first before the script runs, so it only needs to allow a minute or so

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Yes, you can implement in the first line of your function [Utilities.sleep()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#sleepmilliseconds)

So, e.g. `Utilities.sleep(120000)` will make the script pause for 120 000 ms (that is 2 minutes) before running the rest of the script

Comment: Keep in mind that takes away from your script runtime.  So if you have a long script it has a greater opportunity to timeout.

Comment: True, if this is an issue you can create within the function firing onFormSubmit() a [ClockTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder) that fires to run the rest of the funciton after 2 minutes.

Comment: It's a very short script and the run time is quick so it worked a dream, thank you